# how to get the changed value when change the form with vuejs form binding?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

## how to get the changed value when change the form with vuejs form binding?

such as:

the data bind to form:

```
{a:1, b:2, c:3}
```

after changed, it will be:

```
{a:2, b:2, c:3}
```

and how to get the changed data:

```
{a:2}
```

I mean that how to get the changed data such as the attrs a changed, then get the 
    {a:2}

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand your question..but, let me try to explain:

```
<input type="text" v-model="a">
<input type="text" v-model="b">
<input type="text" v-model="c">

{{ $data | json }}
```

You can always use $data to get all $data changes.

```
{
    data(){
        return {
            a:1,
            b:2,
            c:3
        }
    },
    ready(){
        // or use this.$log(...)
        console.log(this.$data);
       // if you want only "a" 
       console.log("a",this.a);
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean that how to get the changed data such as the attrs a changed, then get the {a:2} thanks any way